# the fade-out animation is not working when clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a react app component and I'm trying to add a fade-in and fade-out animation to `.favoritesList` so that when the button `.favorites` is clicked `favoritesList` fades in and when `.favorites` is clicked again `favoritesList` fades out

so far only the fade-in animation is working but the fade-out is not, can someone tell me why ?

Here is the App component code :

```
import './App.css';
import { FaTrashAlt } from 'react-icons/fa';
import SearchIcon from './search.svg';
import { useEffect, useState, useRef} from 'react';
import Cards from './Cards';


const App = () => {
  const API_URL = 'http://www.omdbapi.com?apikey=e25cd079';

  const favoritesListRef = useRef(null);
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [showFavorites, setShowFavorites] = useState(false);
  const [favoriteMovies, setFavoriteMovies] = useState(() => {
    const storedFavorites = localStorage.getItem('favoriteMovies');
    return storedFavorites ? JSON.parse(storedFavorites) : [];
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    searchMovies('marvel');
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('favoriteMovies', JSON.stringify(favoriteMovies));
  }, [favoriteMovies]);

  const searchMovies = async (title) => {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}&s=${title}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    setMovies(data.Search);
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      searchMovies(search);
    }
  };

  const toggleFavorites = () => {
    setShowFavorites(!showFavorites);
    const favoritesList = favoritesListRef.current;
    if (favoritesList) {
      if (showFavorites) {
        favoritesList.classList.remove('fade-in');
        favoritesList.classList.add('fade-out');
        setTimeout(() => {
          favoritesList.style.opacity = '0';
          favoritesList.style.display = 'none';
        }, 500);
      } else {
        favoritesList.style.display = 'block';
        favoritesList.classList.remove('fade-out');
        favoritesList.classList.add('fade-in');
        favoritesList.style.opacity = '1';
      }
    }
  };
  

  

  const addToFavorites = (movie) => {
    setFavoriteMovies([...favoriteMovies, movie.Title]);
  };

  const removeFromFavorites = (movie) => {
    const updatedFavorites = favoriteMovies.filter(
      (favMovie) => favMovie !== movie.Title
    );
    setFavoriteMovies(updatedFavorites);
  };

  


  return (
    <div className="app">
      <header className="header">
        <div className="list-container">
          <button onClick={toggleFavorites} className="favorites">
            Favorites
          </button>
          {showFavorites && (
            <div className={`favoritesList ${showFavorites ? ' fade-in' : ' fade-out' }`}>
              {favoriteMovies.length > 0 ? (
                <ul>
                  {favoriteMovies.map((movie) => (
                    <li key={movie}>
                      {movie}{" "}
                      <button
                        onClick={() => removeFromFavorites({ Title: movie })}
                      >
                        <FaTrashAlt className="trashIcon" />
                      </button>{" "}
                    </li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              ) : (
                <p>No favorites yet</p>
              )}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
        <h1 className="title">Movie Browser</h1>
      </header>
      <div className="search">
        <input
          type="text"
          value={search}
          placeholder="Search for a movie/show"
          onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
          onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
        />
        <img
          src={SearchIcon}
          alt="Search Icon"
          onClick={() => searchMovies(search)}
        />
      </div>
      {movies.length > 0 ? (
        <div className="container">
          {movies.map((movie) => (
            <Cards
              key={movie.imdbID}
              movie={movie}
              toggleFavorites={toggleFavorites}
              addToFavorites={addToFavorites}
              removeFromFavorites={removeFromFavorites}
              isFavorite={favoriteMovies.some(
                (favMovie) => favMovie === movie.Title
              )}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="empty">
          <h2>Opps! looks like the movie/show is not found</h2>
          </div>
        )}
      
      </div>
      
    );
    
  };
  
  export default App;
```

Here is the Cards component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FaHeart } from 'react-icons/fa';

const Cards = ({ movie: { imdbID, Year, Poster, Title, Type }, toggleFavorites, addToFavorites, removeFromFavorites, isFavorite }) => {
  const handleFavoriteClick = () => {
    if (!isFavorite) {
      addToFavorites({ imdbID, Title });
    } else {
      removeFromFavorites({ imdbID, Title });
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="movie" key={imdbID}>
      <div className="year-container">
        <p>{Year}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="favorite-container">
        <button onClick={handleFavoriteClick}>
          <FaHeart color={isFavorite ? "#FF0000" : "white"} className="favIcon"/>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src={Poster !== "N/A" ? Poster : "https://via.placeholder.com/400"} alt={Title} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>{Type}</span>
        <h3>{Title}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Cards;
```

and the CSS code :

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:100,300,400,700");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i");

* {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --font-roboto: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  --font-raleway: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

body {
  font-family: var(--font-roboto);
  background-color: #212426;
}

.app {
  padding: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;

}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


.list-container{
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0;
  

}

.favorites {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FF0000;
  margin-left: 60px;
  font-size: 1.5rem ;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

 
.favoritesList {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 50px;  
}


/* Define the keyframes for the fade-in animation */
@keyframes fade-in {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Define the keyframes for the fade-out animation */
@keyframes fade-out {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to { opacity: 0; }
}

/* Apply the fade-in/out animation to the .favoritesList element */

.fade-in {
  animation-name: fade-in;
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

.fade-out {
  animation-name: fade-out;
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: visible;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;

}


ul {
  margin-left: -30px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li:before {
  content: "-";
  margin-right: 5px;
  opacity: 0.2;
  
}

.poster {
  width: 50px;
  height: 75px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

li{
  color: #FF0000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  right:0;
}

.trashIcon{
margin-left: 100px;
color: #a1a1a1;
cursor: pointer;
}

.title {
  font-size: 3rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.9px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 100%, rgba(249, 211, 180, 0) 100%);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0;

}

.search {
  width: 71%;
  margin: 4rem 0 2rem;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  padding: 1.5rem 1.75rem;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  background: #1f2123;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px #1c1d1f, -5px -5px 7px #222527;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px #1c1d1f, -5px -5px 7px #222527;
}

.search input {
  flex: 1;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: var(--font-raleway);
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-right: 1rem;

  outline: none;
  color: #a1a1a1;
  background: #1f2123;
}

.search img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.empty {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 3rem;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.empty h2 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  color: #f9d3b4;
  font-family: var(--font-raleway);
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.movie {
  width: 310px;
  height: 460px;
  margin: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 13px 10px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.movie div:nth-of-type(1),
.movie div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: #3D0000;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 16px;
  top: 0;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}


.movie .year-container {
 right: auto;
 width: 20%;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 0;
}

.movie .favorite-container {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 0.6rem;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 50%;

}

.movie:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 30px 18px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
}


.movie div:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.movie div:nth-of-type(3) img {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.movie div:nth-of-type(4) {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #3D0000;
  padding: 16px 24px 24px 24px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.movie div:nth-of-type(4) span {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}

.movie div:nth-of-type(4) h3 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  color: #FF0000;
}

button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.favIcon {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .app {
    padding: 4rem 2rem;
  }

  .search {
    padding: 1rem 1.75rem;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .search input {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  .search img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .app {
    padding: 4rem 1rem;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  .container {
    margin-top: 2rem;
  }

  .movie {
    width: "100%";
    margin: 1rem;
  }
}
```

I tried adding classList to the toggleFavorites to be able to add or remove the animations classes but only fade-in seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be mixing a few versions of  the same code - for example your `favoritesListRef` doesn't actually seem to do be used at all. I would clean that up to avoid confusion.

I believe the problem is with this part

```
{showFavorites && (
  <div className={`favoritesList ${showFavorites ? ' fade-in' : ' fade-out' }`}>
    ...
  </div>
)}
```

Here if `showFavorites` is falsy the `div` actually doesn't get rendered at all. The div is removed from the DOM immediately so your fade-in/fade-out check never runs. A simplified example of the same thing:

```
if (user.admin) {
   // Inside here user.admin will _always_ be truthy
   // so my check in the console.log doesn't make sense
   console.log(user.admin ? "Hello admin": "Hello user")
}
```

I would probably go back to the `useRef` route myself and completely remove the `{showFavorites && ...}` check. Not sure if it works for you, but I would maybe also just animate it with JS instead of CSS, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate